# Is there a way to use a variable in a like statement in dbvisualizer

Tags: sql, dbvisualizer

I need to compare 2 fields in **dbvisualizer** using the `like` operator. I keep getting a syntax error. Is it possible to do this?  If so please advise on the syntax.

Just a couple of the things I've tried unsuccessfully:

```
  //first
 where display_nm  like ('%' + first_nm + '%')
 //2nd
 where display_nm  like '%' + first_nm + '%'

select 
   display_nm,
   last_nm,
   first_nm,
   bus_nm
from my_file
   where display_nm like ('%' + first_nm + '%')
```

> 11:12:28  FAILED  [SELECT - 0 rows, 0.006 secs]  [Code: -210056, SQL
>   State: HY000]  [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Syntax
>   error in SQL statement at or about "('%' +first_nm + '%')" (10713)

Comment: What dbms are you using, please tag the question with it. I suppose you are not concatenation the strings correctly but what the right way is depends on what dbms you have

Comment: I'm connecting to OpenEdge RDBMS